# Access .sql script files on other partition or hdd

Tags: postgresql, scripting, postgresql-11

I'm running a Linux Mint 19.1 - Tessa OS, which for you who might not know it is based on Ubuntu 18.04 - Bionic Beaver. On this I have installed postgresql 11 which work well. There is one problem though. For organisational reasons code files are stored in project directories on a separate partition of my hdd. These directories, or actually the complete partition can not be accessed from within the psql environment, even though the `user` account has full access to the partition normally.

To begin with, auto-completing paths with tab doesn't work for the partition and typing the path manually gives a `Permission denied` message. I've tried adding a `su` or `sudo` argument before the `\i` but it doesn't work either. Nor does starting the session from within the partition.

E.g.

```
user@laptop:/$ sudo -u postgres psql
[sudo] password for user:         
psql (11.5 (Ubuntu 11.5-3.pgdg18.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \i /media/user/Storage/Projects/DB_project/script1.sql
/media/user/Storage/Projects/DB_project/script1.sql: Permission denied
postgres=# su \i /media/user/Storage/Projects/DB_project/script1.sql
/media/user/Storage/Projects/DB_project/script1.sql: Permission denied
postgres-# ;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "su"
LINE 1: su 
        ^
postgres=#
```

For now I have to copy the files I want to use to my `/home/` directory, or any directory in that tree, and then make sure to paste any updated files back in the `Projects` directory tree.

Any ideas on how to solve this so I don't need to copy files back and forth all the time?

Comment: Seems more an issue of file system and the rights of the user that postgre uses to launch psql - you can try with a file system link that makes those script and other files available in an accessible directory - of course within the context of psql "su" won't work ... its specific for the regular command shell

Comment: Why do you run `psql` as user postgres? Clearly that user ID can't read files that are owned by you. Run `psql` as yourself and you won't have the problem. It's a bad idea to connect to the database as a superuser (unless _absolutely_ necessary) anyway.

Comment: @mustaccio, postgres is the owner of all the databases, running as any other user won't give me any rights to access or change the database, which is what the script does. I must admit I assumed the postgres user would only be of effect inside psql. Also, both file locations are "owned by me" so I don't really see why I can access one and not the other. As I mentioned, I can access everything on the OS partition, no problem, but nothing on the "Storage" partition. Both partitions are set up with read & write rights for "Other" users.

Comment: Also, trying to run psql as myself gives this: `psql: FATAL:  role "user" does not exist`. I am completely new to this language and this is how all the tutorials I've found tells me to run it.

Comment: @eagle275 Thank you for the tip. However, I just tied it and sadly I get the same problem with `Permission denied` trying to access them through such a link.

Comment: Thank you both for your tips and advice. It turns out that even though `Storage` had read & write permission set for other users `/media/user` did not. Changing this permission solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was much easier to fix than I though. Being completely new to both SQL and postgres I foolishly assumed that psql had something to do with the problem. As it turns out the directory `/media/user` in which `Storage` is mounted did not have Read & Write permissions set for other users, so even though I would have been allowed to access the file inside `Storage` I could not get these.

Changing the permission in `/media/user` solved the problem. In the future I'll make sure that all directories in a path are accessible to me.

Thanks again for the help and advice.